# Apache configurations for request timeout and user session timeout

Tags: php, apache

I have a large photo that I am trying to upload and after about 30 seconds the screen just goes blank and there are no error logs.  One guess is that it might be request timeout time.  How can I increase that in Apache?

Also, while I am at it, how do I extend the user session timeout?

Thanks!

Comment: What programming language is handling the upload?  It may have set its own limits on execution time.

Comment: @Michael PHP and I am using something called ImageGlick which usually works fine except with this jpeg photo of a large size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, you can increase the `max_execution_time` in php.ini.  Also, [`set_time_limit($numseconds)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) can be used in a script.

And I believe 30sec is the default.

Comment: where is the php.ini file usually located? :)

Comment: @GeekedOut: Do a phpinfo(), you can find the location there.